# Правильный вывод значения из массива (функции)

Tags: функции, массивы, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно вывести значение массива?
Есть функция:

```
function test(){
return array('username' => 'test','field' => 'value');
}
```

Но при попытки вывести только значение 'username' ,возникаю проблемы.
Пробовал вот так:

```
echo test()['username']
```

Но это не только выглядит бредово ,но и не работает.

Comment: Работает, но с версии 5.4, что ли. Safe way - через переменную:

    $temp = test();
    echo $temp['username'];

Comment: Через переменную я понимаю, но хотелось бы без использования переменой.

Comment: @Mr_Epic [php 5.4](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php) и выше.

Answer (score 1):

В параметрах функции введи переменную, которая отвечает за вывод, и возвращай не весь массив.
Echo test('username');